# PXDBCreatedDateTime doesn't work in Extension Table

Tags: acumatica

I have a User Defined Table that I link to the BAccount table in Acumatica.  What I'm trying to do is use the PXDBCreatedDateTime attribute to save the CreateDateTime when the UDFs are set.  Is this posssible?  It doesn't seem to work right now.

```
[PXTable(typeof(BAccount.bAccountID),IsOptional=true)]
public class CustomerExtension : PXCacheExtension<BAccount>
{
    [PXDBCreatedDateTime()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Date")]
    public DateTime? CreatedDateTime { get; set; }

    public class createdDateTime : IBqlField { }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume it would not work as the BAccount table already contains a field with the same name 'CreatedDateTime'. I would first use a different field name for table extension fields as this could create some conflicts to those fields that already exist with the same name. Also, extension tables are inserted when the base table is either inserted or updated (first time after extension table is added) which may or may not occur from changes to your extension fields. This would also cause some issues for getting a good date from your PXDBCreatedDateTime field. You might be better off using a standard date time field and use some type of formula to update the date when your fields change. I would have to research the formula. You could use logic inside the setter of your user fields and add the PXDependsOnFields attribute to your date field and set your date field if null. I have not tried PXDependsOnFields in an extension - but the logic could be promising.

Comment: Uh, yeah.  changing the name to CreateDateTime1 just worked.  Duh.  Thanks Brendan!

Comment: Glad to help. We use many extension tables. We start all of our extension fields with the same 2 letters so they are always unique and identifiable as ours (in scenarios where many extensions exist)